# Get Min date as condition

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that contains invoices for all phone numbers, and each number has several invoices, I want to display only the first invoice for precise number but i don't really know how get only first invoice , this is my query

```
SELECT
     b.contrno
     a.AR_INVDATE
     FROM P_STG_TABS.IVM_INVOICE_RECORD a 

     INNER JOIN P_EDW_TMP.invoice b
     ON b.contrno=a.contrno

     WHERE a.AR_INVDATE< (SELECT AR_INVDATE FROM P_STG_TABS.IVM_INVOICE_RECORD WHERE contrno=b.contrno  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT
    t.contrno,
    t.AR_INVDATE
FROM
(
    SELECT
        b.contrno,
        a.AR_INVDATE,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.contrno ORDER BY a.AR_INVDATE) rn
    FROM P_STG_TABS.IVM_INVOICE_RECORD a 
    INNER JOIN P_EDW_TMP.invoice b
        ON b.contrno = a.contrno
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

If you are worried about ties, and you want to display all ties, then you can replace `ROW_NUMBER` with either `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: I just change order by  ASC

Answer (score 3):

Teradata supports a `QUALIFY` clause to filter the result of an OLAP-function (similar to `HAVING` after `GROUP BY`), which greatly simplifies Tim Biegeleisens's answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM P_STG_TABS.IVM_INVOICE_RECORD a 
INNER JOIN P_EDW_TMP.invoice b
   ON b.contrno = a.contrno
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY b.contrno 
         ORDER BY a.AR_INVDATE)  = 1
```

Additionally you can apply the ROW_NUMBER before the join (might be more efficient depending on additional conditions):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 ( SELECT * 
   FROM P_STG_TABS.IVM_INVOICE_RECORD a 
   QUALIFY
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY b.contrno 
            ORDER BY a.AR_INVDATE)  = 1
 ) AS a
INNER JOIN P_EDW_TMP.invoice b
   ON b.contrno = a.contrno
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, then one way is to use `group by` with `min(a.AR_INVDATE)`:

```
SELECT
b.contrno,
min(a.AR_INVDATE)
FROM P_STG_TABS.IVM_INVOICE_RECORD a 
INNER JOIN P_EDW_TMP.invoice b
ON b.contrno=a.contrno
group by b.contrno
```